# php undefined index coming on uploading file with ['name']

Tags: php

```
    <form action='' method='post'>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="kk">
    <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    echo $_FILES["kk"]["name"]; 

    }
    ?>
```

hi,i'm new to php,In this code undefined index kk coming on uploading file,i just want the file name...please help me out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add enctype="multipart/form-data" to form tag

Comment: Thank you verymuch

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `enctype="multipart/form-data"` when you have to upload file

```
<form action='' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="kk">
    <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    echo $_FILES["kk"]["name"]; 

    }
    ?>
```